# Chef Recipe On Vagrant not respecting rest_timeout or timeout option on long-running w-get download

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I'm attempting to wget a large file to be used in a chef recipe - it's a database backup that is around 350mb. I'm using wget to get the file, here's my recipe:

```
include_recipe "apt"

include_recipe "sudo"

execute "sudo mkdir -p ~/dev/dbbackup"

execute "download most recent db backup" do
  command "sudo wget --user=theusername --password=thepassword -P ~/dev/dbbackup/ https://ourdbbackup.com/latest.psql.gz"
  timeout 86400
 end
```

No matter what I've tried, I get the following:

```
[2013-04-23T21:50:32+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[download most recent database backup] action run (company_dev::default line 25)
bash: line 2:  1184 Killed                  chef-solo -c /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/solo.rb -j /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/dna.json
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

I even tried monkey-patching Vagrant so that I could add the rest_timeout option:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise32"
   config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
     chef.cookbooks_path = "cookbooks"
     chef.add_recipe "company_dev"
     chef.log_level = :debug
     chef.rest_timeout = 86400
  end 
end
```

This produces a /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/solo.rb that does have a rest_timeout option:

```
rest_timeout 86400
```

But I still get the same error that Chef can't complete. Any suggestions on getting this large download to work without Chef timing out or some other issue stopping the recipe? It works fine when I setup the machine then run the wget from inside. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Increase the memory of the VM, add the following to `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
   vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]
end
```

Then recreate the VM:

```
vagrant destroy --force && vagrant up
```

PS: why dont you use [`remote_file`](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_remote_file.html) instead of doing `wget`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like problem in dynamic console output that generates wget while downloading file. This causes out of memory error. 
I've fixed this problem by using "curl -O filename download_url".

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with a large file download from an external source using wget.  Changed the command to use `curl -O #{URL}` and the chef-client run no longer failed with an error runKilled error.  Using chef 11.4 on rackspace cloud